# How do I restart a scene in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework

I've been looking for a method to restart the current scene in Phaser but have not been able to find anything that works. I see a lot of people talking about `Scene.restart()` but this method does not seem to exist nor is it documented anywhere in the official documentation. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `this.scene.restart()`, where `this` is the context of the current Scene. *(just **beware** to pass the context, if you are trying use `this` in an event handler or callback function)*

here is the [link to a good offical example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scenes/restart-a-scene), it shows also the passing, of the context(`this`), to the event handler.